# Format data in CSV using ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this kind of data in my csv file,

```
Albany, N.Y.
Albuquerque, N.M.
Anchorage, Alaska
Asheville, N.C.
Atlanta, Ga.
Atlantic City, N.J.
Austin, Texas
Baltimore, Md.
Baton Rouge, La.
Billings, Mont.
Birmingham, Ala.
Bismarck, N.D.
Boise, Idaho
Boston, Mass.
Bridgeport, Conn.
```

I want to convert it into this form:

```
Albany, N.Y.;Albuquerque, N.M.;Anchorage, Alaska;Asheville, N.C.;Atlanta, Ga.;Atlantic City, N.J.;Austin, Texas;Baltimore, Md.;Baton Rouge, La.;Billings, Mont.;Birmingham, Ala.;Bismarck, N.D.;Boise, Idaho;Boston, Mass.;Bridgeport, Conn.
```

What I have got so far:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("test.csv") do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
```

But instead of getting a full row, it's just giving arrays, separated over coma? How is it possible to convert it in this manner?

Comment: With no quoting, you could just do `File.open(fn).read.split(/\n/).join(';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want only to read and print the data?, you could try using map and join:

```
p CSV.foreach('test.csv').map(&:join).join(';')
# => "Albany N.Y.;Albuquerque N.M.;Anchorage Alaska;Asheville N.C.;Atlanta Ga ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
require 'csv'

result = Array.new
CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
  result << row.join(',')
end
puts result.join(';')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no benefit to using the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class here. Just treat it like a regular text file.

```
File.read('test.csv').gsub('\n', ';')
  #=> "Albany N.Y.;Albuquerque N.M.;Anchorage Alaska;..."
```